# Whats the best way to filter below multidimentional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want all the arrays with pubsite_id = 8, whats the optimal way to do it. I can do it using foreach but it seems very expensive when it grows bigger.

```
array(
  array( "startdate"    => "2014-02-01",
         "enddate"      => "2014-02-13",
         "pubsite_id"   => "1",
         "dfp_order_id" => "116260016",
         "amount"       => "-5000.00000",
         "amountperday" => -384.61538461538
  ),
  array( "startdate"    => "2014-02-01",
         "enddate"      => "2014-02-28",
         "pubsite_id"   => "8",
         "dfp_order_id" => "116260016",
         "amount"       => "-700.00000",
         "amountperday" => -25
  ),
  ...
)
```

Comment: A `foreach` will be fine. Prematurely optimising code is rarely useful.

Comment: You need to loop one way or the other. There's no magical way to do it without looping. `foreach` is about the most efficient way to do it., though `array_filter` would read nicer IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Per @deceze's advice, [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) is a nice and clean way to go, and will perform as well as anything else:

```
$filtered_arr = array_filter( $arr, function( $item ) {
  return $item["pubsite_id"] == "8";
} )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($array as $value) 
{
    foreach($value as $key => $val) 
    {
      if($val['pubsite_id'] == "8") 
     {
       /*your stuff */
     }

   }
}
```